# Invalid context 0x0

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext

I've got this `-drawRect` method inside a view:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
for (int i=0; i<[points count]; i++) {
    GraphPoint* point = [points objectAtIndex:i];
    [point.color setFill];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, point.x+point.size/2, point.y+point.size/2, point.size, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

When `[points count]` is equal to 1, everything works amazing, however, when it increases, this error is thrown:

`Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0.`

I think there's something wrong with the loop - it sets the context's color twice or even more times. Don't know how to avoid it. Each point must have its own color and I can't set the context's fill color before the loop.

Please, help! Maybe someone has ever faced this problem?

Comment: Why are you popping a context when you don't push one?

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding what UIGraphicsPopContext does. I assume that you're trying to clear the current path that's set on the context. You want `CGContextSaveGState` and `CGContextRestoreGState`.

Try this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
for (int i=0; i<[points count]; i++) {
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    {
        GraphPoint* point = [points objectAtIndex:i];
        [point.color setFill];
        [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextAddArc(context, point.x+point.size/2, point.y+point.size/2, point.size, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

N.B. I normally create a new scope (with the extra `{` and `}`) when using stack-based operations (push and pop), just so that it's easy to check they're balanced. This is optional, of course.

Comment: Nice tip for using the brackets with push and pop style programming.

Answer (score 1):

You're popping the context on each loop, but you don't push it.  So you're running out of contexts on the context stack.

Remove the UIGraphicsPopContext call and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Ohhh! The problem is solved!

I just needed to reset the context color when the current color of the context and the color of the current point are different!